# Oracle Unified Directory import users with hashed passwords

Tags: oracle, import

We have user data stored in a database table. The passwords are stored as hashed values. We would like to import these users into OUD, retaining the hashed values. From what I can gather from OUD documentation, the various methods to add users all take a clear text password, with the option of encrypting them as part of the import process. Is there a way to import users with already hashed passwords?

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust your OUD configuration. Below config change would allow you to import pre-encoded passwords.

To check the current status of this setting:

```
dsconfig --hostname localhost --port 4444 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" -j /tmp/password.txt --trustAll get-password-policy-prop --policy-name "Default Password Policy" --advanced
```

To change the current configuration to allow pre-encoded passwords:

```
dsconfig --hostname localhost --port 4444 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" -j /tmp/password.txt --trustAll set-password-policy-prop --policy-name "Default Password Policy" --set allow-pre-encoded-passwords:true --advanced
```

If it helps, upvote it!